# How to create call dialog from UIAlertController in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Hi Very new to IOS development in xamarin.

I want to make call from `UIAlertController`. below is code I am trying to make call using `UIAlertController` but something goes wrong i dont understand.

```
   var title = "Call";
    var message = "1234567788";   

    var alertCotroller = UIAlertController.Create (title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

// Create the actions.
 alertCotroller.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create (cancelButtonTitle, UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alertAction =>
 Console.WriteLine ("The 'Okay/Cancel' alert's cancel action occured."));

alertCotroller.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create ("Call", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alertAction =>UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel:"+message)) ));    

PresentViewController (alertCotroller, true, null);
```

[image]

I just want to make call to message number, using `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to test Phone call on simulator.

If you are testing in a real device.
Try this:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel://" + message));
```

If you want to prompt the user instead of calling directly you could use:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("telprompt://" + message));
```

Comment: thanks for rply. can I see the call in emulator so that I can understand how it display to end user

Comment: "tel://" this is req or only "tel:" https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/Phone/dial-phone-uri/

Comment: one more thing I am bit confuse over "UIAlertController" and "UIAlertView" which one I used?

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. It's recommended to use UIAlertController.